# Pagination with CanCan block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate, kaminari, cancancan

With will_paginate or Kaminari you can paginate with scopes and CanCanCan. Explained here, [How to do pagination with cancan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962149/how-to-do-pagination-with-cancan)

But that only explains how to do it if your CanCan ability uses hashes. That won't work if you use a block. Which I understand because the hash translates into an SQL statement. I just can't seem to think of a way to do it with a block statement.

For example:

```
can :read, Shipment do |shipment|
  user.client_ids.include? shipment.client_id
end
```

The user can only look at the shipment if the client is in their list of clients.

```
@shipments = Shipment.ransack(params[:q]).result.uniq.paginate(page: params[:page]).select { |shipment| can? :show, shipment }
```

One way to do it and return an array of your records. But will_paginate requires the pagination object.

```
<%= will_paginate @shipments %>
```

will_paginate will barf all over that. Maybe this would work in Kaminari?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the better way is just to use a hash over a block. It is more efficient anyways. (https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions)

I converted my block to a hash

```
can :read, Shipment, client_id: user.client_ids
```

And in my query chain (https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Fetching-Records)

```
@shipments = Shipment.accessible_by(current_ability, :show).ransack(params[:q]).result.uniq.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

And it works beautifully.